# Proxychains fails but foxyproxy works?

Tags: proxy, proxychains, squid

Here's a proxy problem I am trying to understand.

There's a http squid proxy in 192.168.215.189:3128 . No other ports of the specified IP is exposed externally. I created a foxyproxy proxy and used that to successfully browse other ports of the IP (Port 8080 specifically). I used another tool spose.py to port scan the IP through the proxy and it gave me 2 ports back successfully.

But when I try the same with a proxychains proxy, it fails to do so. I configured the proxychains file and added this line to the configuration file http   192.168.215.189   3128 , as it's just one proxy the type of chain should not matter but I have tried each of them from dynamic, strict and random. The proxy_dns is uncommented in the configuration file. When I try to use proxychains to nmap scan the port 8080 (Which I know is there because I can access it from the browser), it says denied and the port comes back as closed .

I have tried to curl the port 8080 through proxychains but it fails to connect after 0 ms.

Can anyone explain why proxychains is failing ?[[image: Successful with foxyproxySuccessful with spose.py]

[image: Proxychain failing to both curl and nmap]

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that `proxychains` sets up the chain as a HTTP CONNECT request, which Squid blocks by default when trying to connect to standard HTTP ports.

`proxychains` does not currently have a workaround for this problem though.

The explanation of the problem can be found here: https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng/issues/263.